# How to turn a prompt into an input element

Tags: javascript, html, input, calculator, prompt

I'm trying to make a calculator by using prompt. I want to turn the prompt into an input element.

I tried using input with an ID and go into JavaScript and trying to put the input into a variable but I think I did it wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<button id="btn">Click to use Calculator</button>
<h1 id="answer"></h1>
<script src="calculator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Javascript

let click = document.getElementById("btn")

btn.onclick = (event) => {
    var firstNumber = parseInt( prompt("Enter the first number"));
    var secondNumber = parseInt(prompt("Enter the Second Number"));
    var operator = prompt("Enter the operator");
// document.getElementById(answer).innerHTML = (firstNumber + SecondNumber)

    if (operator=="+") {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = (firstNumber + secondNumber)
    }
    else if (operator=="-"){
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = (firstNumber - secondNumber)
    }
    else if (operator=="x"){
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = (firstNumber * secondNumber)
    }
    else if (operator=="/"){
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = (firstNumber / secondNumber)
    }
    else if (operator=="*"){
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = (firstNumber * secondNumber)
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = ("Enter a Valid Number")
    }
    }
console.log(typeof(firstNumber))
```

Comment: `.innerHTML` - you should use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: `<h1 id="answer"></h1>` <-- This is an inappropriate use of the `<h1>` element.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.